# How to enable compression when sending data between two DolphinDB nodes?

Tags: compression, remote-access, remote-server, dolphindb

With DolphinDB Java API, I can enable data transfer in compression mode by setting parameter `compress` to `true` using method `DBConnection`.  I know DolphinDB built-in function `xdb` can help open a remote connection, however I could not find the parameter to enable the data compression. Can anyone explain to me how to enable compression when connecting to a DolphinDB server using DolphinDB script?

Answer (score 2):

Use `xdb` to set up the connection first, then use `remoteRunWithCompression` to enable data compression for your query. The usage of `remoteRunWithCompression` is the same as `remoteRun`.

In this example we are connecting these two nodes:

192.168.0.3:8848 (server)

192.168.0.4:8848 (client)

Let’s first create an in-memory table “testT“ on the server (192.168.0.3:8848) and share it across nodes.

```
n=1000
ID=rand(10,n)
x=rand(1.0,n)
t=table(ID,x)
share t as testT
```

From the client side (192.168.0.4:8848), set up server connection with `xdb` and query the shared in-memory table “testT” with compression enabled.

```
h = xdb("192.168.0.3", 8848, "admin", "123456")
idList = remoteRunWithCompression(h, "select * from testT")
```